# What is the new Input System equivalent of Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")?

Tags: unity, c#, input

At first, it seems that `Mouse.current.delta.x.ReadValue()` would be the most equivalent, but they give different outputs.

The purpose is porting old Input code to the new with 1:1 results. Is this even possible?

Comment: In what way exactly is the output "different"? One thing I could think of is that `Mouse.current.delta` is more equivalent to `Input.GetAxisRaw` than `Input.GetAxis`. But perhaps what you are observing is something entirely different? Can you add more detail?